# Creating a grid with three equal columns stretched horizontally

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to define a grid with three columns and same witdh (that mean each column has with is 1/3 of the total width of grid). And Grid must stretch horizontally.

```
<Border Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition  Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                <ColumnDefinition  Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                <ColumnDefinition  Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="A"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="B"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="C"/>
    </Border>
```

Above code xaml, three column has same width but the grid is not stretch horizontally.
Thanks for helping me :>

Comment: Have you tried setting `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` on your Grid or the Border? Btw the `SharedSizeGroup` have no effect here, they are used if you need to "synchronize" the column widths between multiple Grids.

Comment: If you're not trying to ensure several columns in separate grids have the same widths (as @vesan indicated), you might have some luck replacing the Grid with a UniformGrid e.g. <UniformGrid Columns="3">...

Comment: @vesan, thanks for your support, so how to define a grid with three columns has the same width and stretch horizontally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution that is use `UniformGrid` :

```
<UniformGrid Columns="3" >
    <TextBlock Text="A"/>
    <TextBlock Text="B"/>
    <TextBlock Text="C"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go.

Add HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" to the grid component.

```
<Border>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition  Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            <ColumnDefinition  Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            <ColumnDefinition  Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="A"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="B"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="C"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: Are you sure you tried this? Won't the shared size scope prevent this working - the TextBlock's size to their content and the size scope ensures they all have that same small size?